# Resources: understanding new and create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have controller ArticlesController.

I have resource articles (in routes.rb file).

Why action `articles#new` corresponds `GET /articles/new` request and action `acticles#create` corresponds `POST /articles` request. Why not `POST /articles/new` ?

Comment: I suggest you read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Я читал ) Но я все равно не понял почему POST /articles, а не POST /articles/new

Comment: Do not use native language in SO somebody can read this for education purpose. / `POST` to `/articles` create your resource but `/articles/new` just render form for  your resource.

Comment: OK, after we submitted a form, we navigated to /articles page. And we must rerender 'new' page if passed data is illegal. As a result we have new article form with url /article. It's not logical for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `new` action displays a view in which you have a form that you fill out and submit. In this case, its a form for `articles`. This form *could* be anywhere on your website, but Rails convention holds that it is in your `new` page.

The `create` action takes the information you submitted in the form and tries to create an object. In this case, an `article`. This action does not, by convention, display a view, but redirects to another page. For me, it's usually the `show` page of that newly created `article`.

Comment: Thanks. After we submitted a form, we navigated to /articles page. And we must rerender 'new' page if passed data is illegal. As a result we have new article form with url /article. It's not logical for me.

Comment: And that's the thing with the `render` method. You can render ANY view from a controller, regardless of how logical it is. If you want your routes and views to line up, I'd suggest using `redirect_to (:back)` or `redirect_to new_article_path`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. How I can tell the user that something went wrong if I use `redirect_to new_article_path` way?

Comment: Use `redirect_to new_article_path, notice: "Something went wrong!"` and in your view add `<%= flash[:notice] %>` to where you want to display that message.

Answer (score 1):

It's defined in the RESTful architecture that a POST request to a collection URI (e.g. "/articles") should create a new entry.

As already noted, the "/articles/new" URI is simply displaying the form, and it's not really an element URI (in the RESTful sense). Therefore it would be inproper to POST, PUT or DELETE it.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer